# Essential Windows Services

Tags: windows, services, roles

Im auditing - redoing is more like it - my companies monitoring software.  At the moment I am specifically looking at Windows Server services for each server Role.

I would have thought this would be easier to find online than it has been, but finding a list of required services for each server Role has been harder than I thought.

Is there a de facto list out there?

Comment: nope, taking a look now

Comment: those are desktop services.  Im looking for services based on Server Roll

Comment: I only realized that after I read your question a second time, I aplogize.